# how to create external hive table using array of json objects

Tags: arrays, json, hadoop, hive, user-defined-functions

I have a array of json object like this..

`[
  {
    "id": 2,
    "createdBy": 0,
    "status": 0,
    "utcTime": "Oct 14, 2014 4:49:47 PM",
    "placeName": "21/F, Cunningham Main Rd, Sampangi Rama NagarBengaluruKarnatakaIndia",
    "longitude": 77.5983817,
    "latitude": 12.9832418,
    "createdDate": "Sep 16, 2014 2:59:03 PM",
    "accuracy": 5,
    "loginType": 1,
    "mobileNo": "0000005567"
  },
  {
    "id": 4,
    "createdBy": 0,
    "status": 0,
    "utcTime": "Oct 14, 2014 4:52:48 PM",
    "placeName": "21/F, Cunningham Main Rd, Sampangi Rama NagarBengaluruKarnatakaIndia",
    "longitude": 77.5983817,
    "latitude": 12.9832418,
    "createdDate": "Oct 8, 2014 5:24:42 PM",
    "accuracy": 5,
    "loginType": 1,
    "mobileNo": "0000005566"
  },
  {
    "id": 1,
    "createdBy": 13,
    "status": 1,
    "utcTime": "Oct 14, 2014 4:57:43 PM",
    "placeName": "21/F, Cunningham Main Rd, Sampangi Rama NagarBengaluruKarnatakaIndia",
    "longitude": 77.5983817,
    "latitude": 12.9832418,
    "createdDate": "Sep 15, 2014 12:10:44 PM",
    "accuracy": 5,
    "loginType": 1,
    "mobileNo": "8147708287"
  },
  {
    "id": 3,
    "createdBy": 0,
    "status": 0,
    "placeName": "no",
    "longitude": 0,
    "latitude": 0,
    "createdDate": "Sep 16, 2014 6:45:50 PM",
    "accuracy": 2,
    "loginType": 1,
    "mobileNo": "9861198611"
  },
  {
    "id": 6,
    "createdBy": 0,
    "status": 0,
    "utcTime": "Oct 14, 2014 4:49:47 PM",
    "placeName": "no",
    "longitude": 0,
    "latitude": 0,
    "createdDate": "Oct 8, 2014 6:51:35 PM",
    "accuracy": 0,
    "loginType": 1,
    "mobileNo": "221133447"
  },
  {
    "id": 5,
    "createdBy": 0,
    "status": 0,
    "utcTime": "Oct 14, 2014 4:49:47 PM",
    "placeName": "no",
    "longitude": 0,
    "latitude": 0,
    "createdDate": "Oct 8, 2014 6:43:41 PM",
    "accuracy": 0,
    "loginType": 1,
    "mobileNo": "5585869635"
  }
]`

and i need to create external table in hive using this array of json object, for this i am trying this query which is not working please help me with this query.

`ADD JAR json-serde-1.1.9.2-Hive13.jar;
CREATE EXTERNAL TABLE mobile_structuring_table(
id int,
createdBy string,
status string,
utcTime string,
placeName string,
longitude double,
latitude double,
createdDate string,
accuracy string,
loginType string,
mobileNo string
)
ROW FORMAT SERDE 'org.openx.data.jsonserde.JsonSerDe'
LOCATION '/user/root/mobile_data/rest_api_mobile_data.json'
;`

is the any specific serde required for this kind of json object arrays.

Comment: is there an error you can share?

Comment: table is getting create but once you open it in hcataloge it emits following error `java.io.IOException: org.apache.hadoop.hive.serde2.SerDeException: Row is not a valid JSON Object - JSONException: Missing value at 1 [character 2 line 1]` hence table is being created but of no use.

Answer (score 0):

Remove the square brackets from your json file. It expects them to be in

```
{...........}
{...........}
{...........}
```